# Center component into an component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I need to center a component into another component.
I have one div who have 2 components, the first one is the main and the second is the banner that I want to display on the center of the first.
I have made a jsfiddle to explain my issue

https://jsfiddle.net/CanadianDevGuy/vjb4k9un/38/

```
<div id="app">
  <first></first>
  <second></second>
</div>
```

[Picture of actual diposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCKx5.png)

The main div (with white border need to exactly match the first component (black one) without space at bottom.

I also add display relative because I need the red component follow the black ( still centered )

Comment: you'll need some CSS most likely

Comment: your fiddle demonstrates what your code does ... what is unclear is, what should it do - sounds like a job for *flex* - but, it's unclear

Comment: is it help?: https://jsfiddle.net/pebL4d0t

Comment: At first , the red one is at bottom of the main div, but I need that will be centered on the first one (black) , I also want to remove the empty space made by the red one at the bottom

Comment: @sebs_dev can you change the order of first and second? I mean can we move second inside first?

Comment: @Nitheesh No I need this disposition of component in the div

Comment: @sebs_dev can you check my answer?

Comment: Yes I make some asjustments

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

To make the child element of the exact dimensions as a parent. First, set the width and height of the parent and then make the child full width and height.

```
#app {
    border: 4px solid white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
#element {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#element2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: If the #app doesn't have the same size, can we have a bottom with percent on the #element2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve what you need by setting `height` to the parent.

Please find the Vue implementation of the same here https://jsfiddle.net/9d0vhs3y/

The below snippet is the pure HTML/CSS implementation of the same.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  border: 4px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#element {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#element2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: calc(50% + 25px);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="element">First</div>
  <div id="element2">Second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with the following CSS.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  border: 4px solid white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#element {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

#element2 {
    position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set #app { height: 250px; } then in bottom extra space is removed and second component fit at center.

[enter image description here][1]